# How to boot Ubuntu without triggering cron job?

Tags: cron

I have written a cron job in Ubuntu so that it will shutdown every minute.

Now I am unable to restart my system as it automatically shuts down. Can I bypass the cron job and run Ubuntu, so that I can log in and disable this cron job?

Comment: You can boot from a LiveUSB to edit or remove the appropriate crontab. I must admit that testing a poweroff-system-each-minute job seems a bit extreme for a test. Most folks simply create (touch) a testfile.

Answer (score 2):

**Linux Recovery**

**On boot**: **Press and hold Esc** (or shift) as soon as anything appears on screen
 
**GRUB Menu**: Using **arrow keys**:
Select: **Advanced**
Select: **[kernel.version]... (recovery mode)**
Select: **root - Drop to root shell prompt**
This will mount read only filesystem for default (first admin) user, so you need to remount as read/write:
**Remount as read/write**: `mount -o remount,rw /`
**Fix** or delete your **cronjob**
**Reboot**